# Mosquitto cannot load certificate

Tags: mosquitto

I am new to mosquitto. I've been trying to configure SSL/TLS for mosquitto recently. I followed the tutorial online but the final result is as follows

```
D:\mosquitto>mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
1663013203: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1663013203: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1663013203: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1663013203: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1663013203: Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile 
"d:\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt".
1663013203: Error: Unable to load server certificate "d:\mosquitto\certs\server.crt". 
Check certfile.
1663013203: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or 
directory
1663013203: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib
1663013203: OpenSSL Error[2]: error:140DC002:SSL 
routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
```

I put ca.crt, server.crt and server.key in the certs subfolder of the mosquitto folder.And the configuration in mosquitto.conf is as follows:

```
listener 8883
allow_anonymous true
cafile d:\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt
certfile d:\mosquitto\certs\server.crt
keyfile d:\mosquitto\certs\server.key
require_certificate false
tls_version tlsv1.1
# Config file for mosquitto
#
# See mosquitto.conf(5) for more information.
#....
```

And The code used to generate the key and certificate is as follows:

```
#openssl req -new -x509 -days 3000 -extensions v3_ca -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt
#openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
#openssl req -out server.csr -key server.key -new
#openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt. -days 1000
```

I don't know where am I going wrong? Hope someone can help me out with this. By the way, my computer system is windows. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The errors imply the files are not where you expect them to be. Double check there are no typos in the directory or file names. Other than that are you sure the ca.crt and server.crt are in PEM format?

Comment: Well, both ca.crt and server.crt are in crt format. I followed the video on the Internet and entered some codes, which can generate ca.crt and server.crt. After that, I put the generated ca.crt and server.crt in the corresponding path in mosquitto.conf and run it, The problem I mentioned above happened....Do I need to change ca.crt and server.crt to pem format? If yes, what should I do?

Comment: The file extensions can be any 3 random letters, without details of the command you actually tab to generate the files we really can't say. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73694814/edit) the question to show how you generated the certs/key

Comment: Hallo I have changed my Question and added the code. can you help me to see it what’s wrong with my code?    Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I just solved the problem. The problem lies in the suffix names of ca.crt and server.crt. My computer does not have "crt" at the end of the file after generating the key and certificate according to the above code. "crt" was added later after generating the file, so it appears in the path added to mosquitto.conf problem. I have now removed the generated suffix and it has worked

Comment: This sounds like you have windows explorer set to ignore known file extensions. This is why you should do all of this on the command prompt that will not hide things from you.